# Help understanding the formula for relative error of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, standard-error

I am studying error theory. I don't understand from where does $\ln$ appear at the end

> Consequently, the marginal absolute error of the approximated value of
> the function $y^*$ is calculated by the formula $$
> A_{y^*}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left|f_{x_i}^{\prime}\left(x^*\right)\right|
> A_{x_i} . $$ Then, using the definition of the marginal relative error
> of the approximate value of $y^*$ , we obtain a formula for its
> finding $$
>  \Delta_{y^*}=\frac{A_{y^*}}{\left|y^*\right|}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\frac{\partial\ln f\left(x^*\right)}{\partial x_i}\right| A_{x_i^*} . $$

Comment: Relative error is $\dfrac{\Delta f}{f}$. What’s the derivative of $\ln(f(x))$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I appreciate your comment